# OAuth 2 token of MailChimp API call

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am developing an application from where I would like to create Campaign with list. The application flow is like this, User will click a [Button](https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=0123456789123) then user will redirected to MailChimp login page, User will come back to my site after Logged in where URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home?code=f0f6949c8b5286c38a90aa4820776e14`.This code is Authorization Code.

Now I would like to fetch [Lists](https://us17.admin.mailchimp.com/lists/) of that specific user who is logged in few moments ago. I can fetch my Lists using API key, but I need users Lists, I don't know users API key.

How can do that ?

I think I need OAuth 2 token of MailChimp API call to fetch User's Lists. How can I get OAuth 2 token of MailChimp API call ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the MailChimp documentation (source: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-oauth2/)

## How to Use OAuth2

For developers integrating platforms that require clients to access MailChimp’s servers, we recommend using OAuth2 for authorization. OAuth2 is a secure option that allows third-party applications to access a server without passing user credentials or API keys.

## Before You Start

Here are some things to know before you begin the OAuth2 process.

Our server implements v10 of the OAuth2 specification, and supports Web Server Flow.
On the server side, OAuth2 is pure HTTPS, so we recommend using HTTPS for your redirect_uri.
We don’t expire tokens, so you won’t need to use refresh_token.
Register Your Application

When you’re ready to begin, register your application with MailChimp:

In your MailChimp account, navigate to the Account page.
In the account drop-down menu, click Extras, and choose API Keys.
Under the “Developing an App?” heading, click Register and Manage Your Apps.
Click Register an App.
In the fields provided, input your application’s information and click Create.
When creation is successful, you’ll see an Application created message appear, and more information at the end of your form, including the Client_ID and Client Secret. Do not share the Client_ID and Client Secret.

On this screen, you don’t need to save or change the information. Click Update or Cancel to go back to the Registered Apps page, or close the window.

## Endpoints

OAuth2 exposes three specific endpoints, and one for metadata.

- authorize_uri
  https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/authorize
- access_token_uri
  https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token
- redirect_uri
  Client-side, made available to the browser in use.
- metadata
  https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/metadata

> #### Note
>
> We support wildcards for the redirect_uri so you can provide
>   data-center-specific information for proper API calls. Wildcards work
>   as long as the redirect_uri appears to be a user-registerable domain
>   under a top level domain. For example, if you enter https://co.uk/ as
>   a redirect_uri, wildcard support won’t work. If you enter
>   https://mydomain.co.uk/, wildcard support will work. Domain detection
>   is based on [these criteria](https://github.com/usrflo/registered-domain-libs/).
>
> A redirect_uri will also override the path portion of a URL, as well.
>   For example, a redirect_uri set to https://test.example.com/oauth.php
>   means that any URI starting with either test.example.com or
>   *.test.example.com will work (i.e.: https://test.example.com/somethingelse.php is valid).

## Flow

1. To start your application’s connection to MailChimp, start by sending the user to the authorize_uri.
2. The user will input their username and password to approve your application. “Remember Me” cookies aren’t permitted here.
3. After the user authorizes your application, our server will redirect your user back to the redirect_uri, along with a code you can exchange for an access_token. The code is valid for 30 seconds.
4. Your application should then make an out-of-band request to the access_token_uri using the code our server provided.
5. Our server returns an access_token, which completes the official OAuth2 flow.
6. To complete the MailChimp flow, make another RESTful request using an OAuth2 client to the metadata_uri.
7. Our server will return a datacenter string, API endpoint, and login URL, as described in the following list.

   - dc:
     The data center string, like us1, us2. If your API wrapper is data center aware, use access_token-dc as a standard API key.
   - api_endpoint:
     Use https://{dc}.api.mailchimp.com. If you your API wrapper isn’t datacenter-aware, use this API endpoint and the access_token as your API key.
   - login_url:
     https://login.mailchimp.com

> #### Note
>
> The access_token is used as an API key. Users don’t have access to these keys because they are tied directly to your
>   application. But, the user can de-authorize your application in
>   MailChimp, which removes and invalidates the token.

## Configuration information

## User-Specific configuration

- client_id
  635959587059
- client_secret
  0da3e7744949e1406b7b250051ee1a95
- redirect_uri
  http://192.168.1.8/oauth/complete.php

## MailChimp standard OAuth2 configuration

- authorize_uri
  https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/authorize
- access_token_uri
  https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token
- base_uri
  https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/

## MailChimp custom configuration

- metadata_uri
  https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/metadata